# How should we place fields or controls for same screen if multiple customization

Tags: acumatica

I have a scenario where the same screen is being customized multiple times in different customization. One customization is done by me and others are by different people.

Now, I am running into an issue of putting my controls on the form.

Does the level of customization will make difference? What are the best practices of creating custom fields or controls on the form in such scenario?

For Example, see below screenshot--

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really a case by case matter. Different customizations, different approach required. For sake of brevity let's call configuration C1 and C2.

1. Best case scenario, C1 and C2 publish fine without having
     to set levels. All good, nothing to do.
2. You have a conflict when publishing, after setting different levels C1 Level X and C2 Level X+1 it publish fine. All good, just need to set levels.
3. You have a conflict when publishing with levels, after swapping levels setting C1 Level X+1 and C2 Level X it publish fine. All good, just need to set levels.
4. Examine possibility of merging both customization, this usually is more a business/management decision than a technical issue. If possible, all good, just merge customizations.
5. You have a conflict that can't be fixed by levels or merging customizations. You'll have to find a workaround, this is a case by case matter and workaround will depend heavily on what/where the controls are customized.

One scenario where you could run into trouble is when you delete/recreate a 'container' control. Avoid removing existing containers and re-implementing them. Adding new one is fine, you'll just have to adjust level if 2 customization use it. Container controls are the parent node in customization, in red in picture, the green ones are the child and are less prone to conflict:
[image]

Comment: How would I place controls on column 4 of summary page when I do not have that form with column added to it which is part of another customization and now when I add it just messes the form layout.

So for example- In the above screenshot where I have Pick List Notes and Accounting checkbox in column 4 in my customization but there is another customization which has already added column 4 with there controls. Now when I move the checkbox in column 1 then it just layout is all mess.

Comment: In that scenario, your customization (C2) depends on another customization (C1). You need to set level of C1 lower than C2 so that it publishes first. Publish C1 then in C2 add your controls.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have no trouble adding the new fields, you just don't like how they are layout in the final rendering. In that case you'd have to consider where you add your fields. Worst case scenario you would have to create another column in the form. When controls overlap more than one column like the Description field it will move all controls to fit the reactive design, it will do so regardless of the number of customization so you'd have to make description smaller than 2 column, place your field at the absolute bottom or in a new column.

Comment: You can also try increasing Form Height, from your screenshot there's no room to put control where you want them so I guess it just pushes thing to the right.